# Rails Render Partial in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been trying to render one of my partials in a helper function located within my controller.

The first issue I encountered was that the helper was returning the each loop instead of the result of the loop. To remedy this I attempted to have it return a string containing the results of the loop.

```
def display_replies(comment)
    if comment.replies.count > 0
        string = ""
        comment.replies.each do |reply, index|
        string = string + (render partial: "comment", locals: {index: index}).to_s.html_safe
        end
        string
    end
```

Called in View with `<%= display_replies(reply) %>`

When I look at my view, what is returned and displayed is HTML, however it is escaped and thus plain text, it looks something like this:

```
["<div class='c comment'>\n<div class='profile'>\n<img src='/assets/profile_image_sample.jpg'>\n</div>\n<div class='message'>\n<div class='username'>Will Leach</div>\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus adipiscing purus et mi aliquet malesuada. Curabitur porttitor varius turpis eget sollicitudin. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus consectetur tortor, nec aliquet lacus tempus vitae. Sed felis massa, dapibus in arcu sit amet, rhoncus condimentum eros. Etiam rutrum lectus in malesuada aliquam. Mauris vitae diam vel felis accumsan vulputate vel nec tortor. Nunc pretium hendrerit est, ut cursus ipsum commodo sit amet.\n<div class='reply-link'>\n<a href='#'>Reply to Comment</a>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n"]
```

I would simply like this to be regular unescaped HTML. I read somewhere that adding html_safe would fix this, but alas it hasn't.

Where to go from here?

Comment: As a meta-reponse, this isn't how you should be using a helper. A helper shouldn't be aware of the underlying templates or data it's being used on. You should be using a partial itself to loop through the replies and using `render partial:` in your templates.

Comment: The thing is I need it to be recursion, and I dont think I can get that with blocks? I need the function to call itself to see if the reply has any reply of its own and if that reply has a reply etc? Can this be done with a partial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, html_safe should be used like this:-

```
<%= display_replies(reply).html_safe %>
```

Comment: Ok so this renders the HTML perfectly, however I am still left with many `\n`

Comment: the html is rendered but the `\n` newline remains and is not converted to a new line

Comment: Instead of putting newline, use <br /> tag

Comment: it is a product of the render function, so the `/n` seems to be automatically inserted by rails

Answer (score 1):

To fix `\n` and `["`, we need to have `.join` after the loop. Like so:

Helper:

```
def display_replies(comment)
  if comment.replies.count > 0
    raw(
      comment.replies.map do |reply, index|
        render 'comment', index: index
      end.join
    )
  end
end
```

View:

`<%= display_replies(reply) %>`

Note that I removed all `html_safe` and replaced with `raw`. And instead of `each` loop, I used `map`, so we don't have to create variable `string` and return it after the loop.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html_safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=html_safe) method like this

```
<%= html_safe display_replies(reply) %>
```